# Importing RSI of cryptocoins to my Excel sheet

Tags: excel

i am creating my own dashbord to follow my operations and Market of Cryptocoins.

I would like to import to Excel the RSI index (Relative Strength Index), but i am not finding a good way to do that. Currently i am using the option DATA > FROM WEB in excel, putting the site Investing.com and loading the entire page (there is no option to check only the table I desire). So, there are a lot of unliked data and it takes tooo long to load because there are a lot of unnecessary information being loaded.

Can anyone give me a light? 
[this is the only thing I want to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDqte.png)

Thank you

Comment: If this is just reporting you may want to consider Power BI (free) which has great web page scraping tools: https://datachant.com/2017/03/30/web-scraping-power-bi-excel-power-query/

Comment: I dont know why, but my Excel is not loading anything when I try to put this address where the data I want is: https://www.investing.com/currencies/xrp-btc-technical?cid=1054876

When i put the main site, www.investing.com it is OK. and I can follow this great blog you have indicated me